# Upgrading to Team Foundation Service from TFS2010

Tags: azure-devops

I work for a company that has a small development team (~30) distributed across multiple continents and multiple development platforms (Windows & OSX). As is such, Team Foundation Service seems like a great way to have a high-availability source control that works well with different development platforms. We're currently using TFS2010 and have about 20,000 checkins in our checkin history. If we were to move to TFService, we'd like to be able to bring the Source Control history with us.

- Is this possible?
- If possible, are there any guides available covering how to do this upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Team Foundation Service seems like a great way to have a
>   high-availability source control that works well with different
>   development platforms.

I can't vouch for multiple platforms (yet), but for all things Windows-related I have been extremely pleased with TFS "in the cloud".

This article looks promising: [Migrating from an On-Premises Team Foundation Server to Team Foundation Service Preview Using the TFS Integration Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj130558.aspx)

> In this article, I demonstrate a migration from an on-premises
>   Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2010 to Team Foundation Service
>   Preview, which uses the latest TFS Integration Tools.
>   ...
>   The TFS Integration Tools help you move yet keep the integrity of
>   version control (VC) data, work item tracking (WIT) data and the links
>   in both.

The crux of the article seems to be the usage of the TFS Integration platform, found [here on Codeplex](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

Note that TFS Preview recently (October 2012, I believe) went live so it is no longer a "preview".

A good search phrase for this process seems to be "migrating on-premise TFS to cloud".

Comment: I can report that my first attempt at using this tool was not successful, but it still looks promising and I will attempt at a later date.

Comment: If you encountered specific error(s), you can post them as another question. I imagine many people will be trying to perform the same type of migration now that the service is live.

Comment: The integration tool is the way to bring your history into the service, but it is very difficult to get right. We do plan to make this better, but it's not going to be soon.

Comment: What's the story on this now @BuckHodges? (+6 months) The same?  We too would like to migrate from on-premise TFS 2010 to Team Foundation Service.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is still the same. We do want an import tool that makes this really good. That's high on our list, and I expect to have it next year (not that there's much left of 2013).